# syntax for django queryset exists

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose I have Django models like this:

```
class Foo(Model):
    bar = ForeignKey(Bar, related_name="foos")

class Bar(Model):
    dummy = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False)
```

I know that I can get all Foo object for a bar using bar.foos.all(). Suppose I just want to see if a bar has any Foos. What is the syntax for this:

```
Option 1:
bar.foos.exists()

Option 2:
bar.foos.all().exists()
```

Which of the above is correct? Every example I have seen of exists() uses filter() so I'm not sure what to do if I don't need to filter.

Comment: Both are fine. The related manager calls the queryset method internally. Don't forget the `'s'` though ;-)

Comment: perfect thanks! I edited the code to add back the 's' i forgot :-)